# Opening New Card on Modal in React

Tags: reactjs, simplemodal, card

I need to create 3 cards dynamically . Initially I need to load 1 card only . On click of button in first card , modal will pop up and on closing modal with save , second cards should be created dynamically and similarly clicking button in second card and saving it  , third card should be created .
Any help is highly appreciable .

Comment: https://codepen.io/amarish-kumar/pen/Exyzdvd?editors=001